# Conditonal statement for iPad

Tags: conditional-content

I need to hide the branding section of my blog, but only when someone is viewing it from the iPad. I am not sure how to attack this.

EDIT: the function `remove_access` currently works in my template, but I need to add the iPad function.

So would this look correct for trying to hide the area:

```
<?php 
function remove_access() {
 if(is_page(array(63, 386, 391, 405, 'forums'))) {
    remove_action('thematic_header','thematic_blogtitle',3);
    remove_action('thematic_header', 'thematic_blogdescription',5);
    remove_action('thematic_header', 'thematic_brandingclosing',7);
    remove_action('thematic_header','thematic_access',9);
    remove_action('thematic_footer','thematic_siteinfoopen',20);
    remove_action('thematic_footer','thematic_siteinfo',30);
  }
}
if( preg_match('/ipad/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ){
    add_action('template_redirect', 'remove_access');
}
```

EDIT-3:

the complete function

changed the condition to: if (it's an iPad AND page is blog) OR (if it's one of the pages in array), then remove items.

```
<?php
function remove_access() {
    if( preg_match('/ipad/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && is_page('blog') || is_page(array(63, 386, 391, 405, 'forums')) ){
        remove_action('thematic_header','thematic_blogtitle',3);
        remove_action('thematic_header', 'thematic_blogdescription',5);
        remove_action('thematic_header', 'thematic_brandingclosing',7);
        remove_action('thematic_header','thematic_access',9);
        remove_action('thematic_footer','thematic_siteinfoopen',20);
        remove_action('thematic_footer','thematic_siteinfo',30);
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'remove_access');
```

EDIT-4:

Add a function to remove from child pages as well. I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
function remove_access() {
if( preg_match('/ipad/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && is_page('blog') && ($post->post_parent == 'blog') || is_page(array(63, 386, 391, 405, 'forums')) && ($post->post_parent == (63, 386, 391, 405, 'forums')) ){
    remove_action('thematic_header','thematic_blogtitle',3);
    remove_action('thematic_header', 'thematic_blogdescription',5);
    remove_action('thematic_header', 'thematic_brandingclosing',7);
    remove_action('thematic_header','thematic_access',9);
    remove_action('thematic_footer','thematic_siteinfoopen',20);
    remove_action('thematic_footer','thematic_siteinfo',30);
  }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'remove_access');
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. you want to remove those things if it's one of the listed pages OR an iPad?

Comment: Both. I need those areas to be hidden because they are only being accessed through an iPad app. The original function works fine because I don't have actual links on the website to access them. However, the blog is accessible from both the website navigation and the iPad app. I don't want those areas to display if the user is using an iPad. Hopefully I am clear, I have a tendency to be too vague sometimes...

Comment: I edited your code, see if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Perfect, I knew there was a way to combine them. I just wasn't piecing it together in my head. That's a huge help. Thank you!

Comment: Here's another question for you. actions are removed from those pages, however, it seems the child pages still show those areas. How can I hide those areas if they are child pages as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's no foolproof method for doing this, but a quick and simple solution is to look at http user agent:

```
<?php
if( preg_match('/ipad/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ):
    echo "is iPad";
endif;
```

Comment: So would this look correct for trying to hide the area:

Comment: @chris_s - edited your code to fix the `if()` statement. `if(): endif;` is just a newer alternate syntax of `if(){ }`. I also moved it to check around the `add_action`, but I suppose you could do it either way.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/), which is a constantly-updated, open-source device description repository. Follow [these instructions](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/nphp/) to set up the API on your Wordpress install, and then you'll be able to query the WURFL database for "[WURFL ID: apple_ipad_ver1](http://www.tera-wurfl.com/explore/?action=wurfl_id&id=apple_ipad_ver1)"